# No candidate version available for tshark

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I got this error when i execute my chef

> No candidate version available for tshark

```
Chef::Exceptions::Package
-------------------------
No candidate version available for tshark

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /root/chef/cookbooks/kamailio-trunk2/recipes/default.rb

 23:   package pkg do
 24:     action :install
 25:   end
 26: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /root/chef/cookbooks/kamailio-trunk2/recipes/default.rb:23:in `block in from_file'

yum_package("tshark") do
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "tshark"
  flush_cache {:before=>false, :after=>false}
  declared_type :package
  cookbook_name :"kamailio-trunk2"
  recipe_name "default"
end
```

this is the code on istalling tshark :

```
# debug tools
%w{tshark}.each do |pkg|
  package pkg do
    action :install
  end
end
```

what is the possible problem . . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no package available in your configured yum repositories names `tshark`. At least on RHEL and CentOS the `/usr/bin/tshark` command is provided by the `wireshark` package.